# javascript file not available from wwwroot/js folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm trying to add a custom javascript file so I can reference it from a razor page.

I placed this file in the wwwroot/js folder

[image]

However, the file is not available client side, and when I check the sources using developer tools in the browser I can only see site.js.

[image]

I tried setting the properties of the js file to copy always, but this has no effect.
(site.js has 'do not copy' as standard)

I'm also refreshing the browser with ctrl+R.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The js `site.js`  is added in `_layout.cshtml` so that
you can see it in developer tools.If you want to see 'test.js' in developer tools,you need to add

```
<script src="~/js/jfc/test.js"></script>
```

to the view which you want to use it or add it to `_layout.cshtml`.

result:

[image]

**Update:**

You can see the following code in `_layout.cshtml`:

```
@await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
```

And if you want to add js to your view,you can add it to

```
@section scripts{

    <script>
       ...
    </script>
}
```

Here is an official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/layout?view=aspnetcore-5.0) about layout.

Comment: Thanks for the input, however I did add this line to my view. The file is still not visible in developer tools + I get errors for missing functions.

Comment: If you add it to `_layout.cshtml`,can it work?

Comment: I tried adding it to the _layout file, but no difference.

Comment: Do you have any error in your devtools Console?